# Using MediaRecorder In a MS Teams Meeting Stage App

Tags: iframe, microsoft-teams, web-mediarecorder

I'm building out an MS teams app and I want to be able to record the app's content. For this, I was trying to use the [MediaRecoderAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) via a React plugin and then using `getUserDisplay` to get access to the user's screen.

For development, I have built the app using the [In Meeting App](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/main/in-meeting-app) as a starting point and have my app tunneled via `ngrok`.

When I access the application via browser and choose "Start Recording", I get a permission dialog that I can accept and the recording works perfectly fine.

[image: normal_browser_access]

However, when I upload the app to Teams and click "Start Recording", since the app is served within an iframe, there is no permission dialog box and the MediaRecorder gets stuck on "acquiring media"

[image: teams_app_issue]

Any idea how I can give the iframe-d Teams app permission to record it's own content using `MediaRecoderAPI` and if not then what the alternative is? I came [across a project](https://github.com/sprider/spfx-teams-tab) that seems to imply it can be done, but it's a fairly old project so I'm unsure if things have changed since then.

Appreciate any pointers

Comment: Could you please share the error logs/exceptions which you are getting.

Comment: Hey Chetan, There's no error shown at all. But I had a question that I think may be the cause. Can I access the content within the  app iframe using  [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia)? 

I think the example I posted above uses `getUserMedia` i.e the camera feed but I want to use `getDisplayMedia` to access the app contents. If I use `getUserMedia` then I am able to access camera feed in the app, but not able to use `getDisplayMedia`

Comment: We are also not able to access display capture in Teams application. We are checking this internally. We will provide you with an update.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs supported by Microsoft Teams are mentioned in [Request device permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile) documentation. For other APIs please help by raising it on [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and so far it looks like the iframe into which the app is loaded doesn't get the `attribute="display-capture *"`